# JSON in longtext in mariabd returns "Could not convert database value to Doctrine type json"

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, mariadb

Symfony 5, I write my `User` entity code accordingly with:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#denying-access-roles-and-other-authorization

and I use mariadb

```php
public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles[] = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }
```

and I added manually an user with role `ROLE_ADMIN`.

I don't understand why it returns the error:

> Could not convert database value "ROLE_ADMIN" to Doctrine Type json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote, I use MariaDB.
On MariaDB help, we can read :
look https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json-data-type/

So I try to replace in my entity (src/Entity/User.php)

```php
public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles[] = json_encode($this->roles);
        …
```

but it is a bad way as @yivi wrote, the first error is at value in db :
be careful also if you define manually, like me, an user in database, that you enter for example `["ROLE_ADMIN"]` an not `ROLE_ADMIN` which could returns an other error `Notice: Array to string conversion` because I have a second error :

```php
$roles[] = $this->roles;
//instead of
$roles = $this->roles;
```

Stupid typing error

Comment: This is wrong. why are you `json_encode`ing to the `$roles` array?

Comment: @yivi, you're right, finally I remove json_encode and wrote only ROLE_ADMIN in db, BUT after switch @ORM\Column(type="json") to "string" to test, otherwise, I have the error `Notice : Array to strig`, if I put ["ROLE_ADMIN"] in db, − One more time, some guys put -1 without comments (of course, it is not me)

Comment: and this Notice error is because my typing error $roles[] instead $roles =…

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in my answer, if you choose a JSON column type, you need to store a valid JSON in the column. It's probably better you leave at JSON and fix it as I mentioned in my answer, or else you won't be able to have more than one role per user.

Answer (score 5):

You get that error because you are setting the value to something that's an **invalid JSON**. If you are going to modify your DB directly, you should put a valid value for a JSON type. In this case it would be something like:

```json
["ROLE_ADMIN"]
```

instead of:

```
ROLE_ADMIN
```

Additionally, you picked the incorrect column type. While `JSON` is an alias for `LONGTEXT` on MariaDb, on `JSON` typed columns a constraint is added. As explained in the docs you linked:

> In order to ensure that a a valid json document is inserted, the JSON_VALID function can be used as a CHECK constraint. This constraint is automatically included for types using the JSON alias from MariaDB 10.4.3.

This would have alerted you that the data you had entered manually was not a valid JSON document.

There is absolutely no need of changing the default `getRoles()` method you show. That one would work perfectly fine, if you are using a JSON type for the property as the error shows.